# Can Lua be used for app development on it's own?

Tags: android, ios, lua

Whilst a few questions mention using Lua in conjunction with some other language, I was wondering if it would be possible to create an app for iOS and Android solely in Lua. If it isn't possible could you recommend a suitable language? C# is a contender as in various forms each platform supports it. C++ is also a possibility with some fiddling around.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "solely in Lua?"

Comment: I mean building the app without any other language, no objective-c or anything like that. All the references I found were Lua with some other language and I was wondering if it was possible to use this language alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Corona SDK. http://developer.coronalabs.com/

Comment: Brilliant thanks. This may be exactly what we're looking for.

Comment: Whilst a great sdk for such app development, is it possible (though I fear I may know the answer already) to develop using this sdk for none mobile based platforms? Windows and Mac OS X so forth?

Answer (score 2):

[Moai](http://getmoai.com/moai-faqs.html) is an alternative to CoronaSDK for developing solely in Lua.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks brilliant too and I'll have to try them both out to see which is best for the project.

Answer (score 1):

For non-mobile platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac) I recommend [LÖVE](http://love2d.org).